# Excel vba code to print

Tags: excel, printing, vba

So with your guys help I made a macro that would read down a singular column and find the last cell that has data entered into it. I then wanted to add nested if then elseif statements that would tell it to print x number of pages based on when the last cell is listed. This is the code im using. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
    'Updateby20150305
    Dim xLastRow As Long
    With Application.ActiveSheet
        xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox xLastRow

    If xLastRow = "22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,30,40,41,42,43,44,45" Then

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Preview:=True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am aware that my print command is in comments, i put that in there temporarily while i was working on something else.

Comment: I may have just figured it out, the sheet number is incorrectly labeled.

Comment: Nope, that wasnt the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `Select Case` with this types of scenarios. I also suggest explicitly stating which worksheet to consider, instead of `ActiveSheet`. If you have multiple sheets, you can pass the sheet into this sub in an argument and call from another sub.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastRowInOneColumn()

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With MySheet

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case True

            Case LastRow > 21 And LastRow < 46

                Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                'Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Preview:=True

        End Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the benefit of using Case statements over If Then Else statements? I do think it has a look of cleaner code but are there are other benefits?

Comment: @Gehn47 - Benefit is ease of readability in a lot of cases because adding additional criteria and is very easy. However, there are cases where `If Then ElseIf` may be cleaner. Good thing is both options are there for you to use as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try this

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
'Updateby20150305
Dim xLastRow As Long

With Application.ActiveSheet
    xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

MsgBox xLastRow

If xLastRow >= 22 And xLastRow <= 45 Then
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Preview:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think thats perfect, then for pages 2,3 etc i would just use else if statements correct.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to split this into pages of up to 23 lines?

Comment: No the first page has other stuff on it where the user doesnt input any data.

Comment: What I mean is, might you have enough lines to print e.g. four pages and you want the code to cover any number of rows?

Comment: No the general idea is for the user to be able to just press a button and it will print the correct number of pages depending on where they last input the data. Later on, im going to improve it so it only prints up to where they last put data and ignore anything after but one step at a time.